# Autoscroll page down in jquery with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add this functionality like auto scroll down using jquery or any other plugin?

http://www.nextbigsound.com/premier/beta

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery animate, to scroll

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 200
}, 400);
```

This will scroll down 200 pixels in 400 milliseconds